# jmeter jsonpath expression for length for the array

Tags: java, arrays, jmeter, beanshell, jsonpath

I have a jmeter test which should exit when the response array is null. To test this, I'm accessing array and checking length in the beanshell assertion. 
I have tried

jsonpath Expression:$.x.length

where as in html response the array looks like {"x":[]}. I got 
"xtract failed com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Path 'length' is being applied to an array. Arrays can not have attributes". How do I test if the array is null or array length null or zero. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `()` on the function, i.e.:

```
$.x.length()
```

See example [here](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath/blob/86ea0ac06244eb0d8140efc69f246989c0b350e8/json-path/src/test/java/com/jayway/jsonpath/internal/function/JSONEntityPathFunctionTest.java)